# How do I map Hibernate collections with Oracle's NOT NULL column constraint enforced?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, foreign-keys, ora-01400

I have 2 tables, ENQUIRY and ELEMENT with a One-to-Many relationship such that an Enquiry has many Elements.

I would like to enforce Oracle's NOT NULL constraint on foreign key column ELEMENT.ENQUIRY_ID as this is best-practice. I have the following collection on the Enquiry object:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "ENQUIRY_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
private Set<Element> elements = new HashSet<Element>();
```

When I enforce the NOT NULL constraint I receive the following stacktrace:

> Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("ELEMENT"."ENQUIRY_ID")

So Hibernate is obviously persisting the collection of elements before the parent enquiry and then going back and doing an UPDATE on the foreign key field afterwards.

Is there a way to enforce the NOT NULL constraint on the collection foreign key field?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `nullable = false` in `@JoinColumn`?

Comment: Thanks axtavt, that worked, easy when you know how!
I can't find a write-up anywhere - though may not be searching correctly - but have blogged about the scenario, your solution, and how Hibernate is interpreting the annotations at http://www.andrew-eells.com/2011/01/09/hibernate-foreign-key-collections-database-best-practice/